# Front-end authentication without a back-end serving cookies on page load?

Tags: authentication, go, reactjs

Is there any way a front-end tool like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) can be used effectively to authenticate users without a backend serving cookies on page load?

Comment: I'm not too sure what's your question here. Frontend can access cookies, see Document.cookie for javascript. A more modern solution is using localstorage. However, both those solutions should not be trusted too much by a backend since they can be modified by the user.

Comment: As the "front-end" executes (lives) on the client-side you CAN do this, but you would Never Ever want to. Authentication means they need to be verified prior to accessing data. If the means for authentication can be seen by the user it is always insecure.

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking. Thank you kindly for the advice!